# Retrieving time for microbenchmarking scripts with millisecond-level accuracy

Tags: shell, time

I want to read a file using shell script and here want to calculate the time required to read a file. I have created below method to get the time in milliseconds at the start and end of the file reading and I will calculate the time difference, but it is not adding the hour+minute+seconds and showing me that the required numeric input.

Method

```
  getCurrentTimeInMili()
   {
    hourTime=$(($(date +%H)*3600))
    minuteTime=$(($(date +%m)*60))
    secondTime=$(date +%S)
    timeInMili= $(($hourTime + $minuteTime + $secondTime));
    return timeInMili
   }
```

Error 
    ./testshell.sh: line 17: return: timeInMili: numeric argument required

Comment: how about the time command? bash$ time ./script ?

Comment: There's another problem here -- return values are limited to 0-255; shell functions should emit content to stdout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoking `date` multiple times means that their return values can be a bit out of sync with each other -- which could be bad if we're invoked just before a second boundary. Better is to call date only once and retrieve all the information desired, like so:

```
getCurrentTimeInMili() {
  date +'%H 3600 * %M 60 * + %S + 1000 * %N 1000000 / + p' | dc
}

startTime=$(getCurrentTimeInMili)
sleep 5
endTime=$(getCurrentTimeInMili)
```

If you don't need this much accuracy, you can simply use the `time` builtin, as in:

```
time sleep 5
```

Comment: yes this is useful. do u know how to get time in miliseconds too. Means i want time in hour, minute, seconds and miliseconds

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar reworked this to work in milliseconds (and use only one date invocation).

Comment: The above answer had one mistake. Instead of %m, it should be %M as %m is for month while %M is for Minute. (via anonymous user suggested edit)

Answer (score 3):

omit the space between `timeInMili=` and `$`

```
timeInMili= $(($hourTime + $minuteTime + $secondTime));
           ^
          This to

timeInMili=$(($hourTime + $minuteTime + $secondTime));
```